# ReplayKit stops screen recording in background mode of the application or outside the app?

Tags: ios, swift4.2, screen-recording, replaykit

I've implemented screen recording with ReplayKit in foreground mode of the application. But when I'm going outside the app with home button app stops background record. 
--> There is an app available In App Store which allows background screen record. 
--> If I have to use Broadcast upload and UI extension then please provide me some programming guide. I've added both in my app but still it stops recording in background mode.

Below is my code

```
import UIKit
import ReplayKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func btnStartRecord_Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if recorder.isAvailable {
        if !recorder.isRecording {
            recorder.startRecording { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func btnStopRecord_Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if recorder.isAvailable {
        if recorder.isRecording {
            recorder.stopRecording { (previewVC, error) in
                if let previewController = previewVC {
                    previewController.previewControllerDelegate = self
                    self.present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate {
func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
    previewController.dismiss(animated: true) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to use a broadcast extension. Once you do that you no longer need to use replay kit.  You need to show the code you have attempted.

Comment: I have added my recorder code and Then I have just added both extensions. But how can I handle recorded video from background of app ?

Comment: Any one find solution for this? Can u guide me?

Comment: I need some solutions too